# What is the correct formulation of momentum balance for a body of continuum?

Tags: momentum, differentiation, continuum-mechanics, navier-stokes, solid-mechanics

What is the correct form of the momentum balance equation
for a continuum body $\mathscr{B}$
whose particles are
fixed,
and occupies volume $V(t)$ at time $t$?

\begin{align}
 &\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\mathrm{\int}_\mathscr{B}
 {u_i\mathrm{d}m}=F_i\\
 \end{align}or\begin{align}
 &\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\int_{V(t)}
 {u_i\rho\mathrm{d}V}=F_i
\end{align}?

where $u_i$ is velocity, and $F_i$ is the applied force to $\mathscr{B}$.

It is strange that the two forms seem to be correct, although $\mathscr{B}$ does not change with time, while $V(t)$ does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should just be a matter of notation and both formulations are equal. (Perhaps you give a reference to where that notation is from.) Whether you write down the mass element as $\text{d}m$ or $\rho\, \text{d}V$, whether you parametrize the body by points in a manifold (which is my guess as to what $\mathcal{B}$ refers to) or via the volume $V\left(t\right)$ it occupies at time $t$ (this should be the image of what Truesdell and Noll call a configuration of the body $\mathcal{B}$ (a smooth homeomorphism into $\mathbb{R}^3$)) - as long as you know what you are doing with this notation both are fine.

Comment: Do you suggest any course/module in any university/education platform that introduces me to *manifold* and *homeomorphism* concepts, and that ideally covers Truesdell's book, *The elements of continuum mechanics*?

Comment: Really depends on where you study and the background you already have. What a homeomorphism is: you should learn this in your first year (at least where I studied (physics) this was part of Analysis 1/Analysis 2). For manifolds you could attend courses on differential geometry. We're talking about advanced (more or less, depends) mathematics lectures here. It really depends on what you aim to do. If you are into theory, you'll enjoy that and realize along the way that the concept of manifold is just the right starting point for a material body.

Comment: If you are an engineer, more interested in experimentation or simulation, you are less likely to ever need the knowledge about manifolds etc. and in the above you can work with the second formulation of conservation of momentum.